# how to maintain text justification after forcing a new line

Tags: horizontal-alignment, line-breaking, text-decorations

How to break a line of text (`\newline` or `\\`) and still maintain justification for its texts?

Comment: Why do you want to do this?

Comment: only have one short three letter word in the new line if I don't force! Thus, I want to have 3 other words in the new line to make document look better.

Comment: Rather than force a linebreak it is better just to _stop_ the break you do not want by ending the paragraph `blah blah blah~abc.` so it will not break before abc.

Comment: A different way to fix the problem is to persuade TeX to set the text *tighter*, so paragraph is a line shorter than its natural length. Try adding `\looseness=-1` at the *start* of the paragraph. This might not work on a short paragraph where TeX can't find a good way to break the lines.

Answer (score 41, accepted):

`\\` (which you should almost never use) is for leaving the line short. `\linebreak` (which you should almost never use) is the command to force a line and still justify the paragraph.

`\linebreak` has an optional argument, such that `\linebreak[3]` (or 2) will only break if the break makes the result not too spaced out.

Rather than force a linebreak it is better just to stop the break you do not want by ending the paragraph `blah blah blah~abc`. so it will not break before abc. That way if you edit the text and this is not needed at all it just acts as a space without affecting the paragraph breaking.

Comment: you should mention that \linebreak has an optional argument, such that \linebreak[3] (or 2) will only break if the break makes the result not too spaced out.

Comment: @FrankMittelbach done:-)

Comment: You mention that one should almost never use `\linebreak`. I'm working in a multi-column environment right now, and the default behavior of latex is leaving many words overhanging, such that they intersect the subsequent column. Manually adding `\linebreak` fixes this, but is there some better way?

Comment: certainly there are better ways. do you have hyphenation set up correctly? that is the first thing to check, then try `\raggedright` or `\sloppy` or ... Adding manual line breaks should be the absolute last resort, it makes your tex document very fragile  and any change to the page size you have to manually change every hand inserted line break. @MRule

Comment: `\raggedright` is not quite what I was looking for, since it removes justification. `\sloppy` is better, but it removes *all* words that overhang. I'd like to stop words overhanging by so much that they collide with the next column. I'm a bit surprised that the default configuration of the article class doesn't handle this. The article I'm editing doesn't override any hyphenation settings, so if there is an issue here it is with the default configuration values. Maybe its a bug in my implementation?

Comment: If you are writing in German using the default US English hypenation rules TeX will not be able to sensibly break any long words so they will make overfull boxes, so you need to specify German (or whatever language) that's what I meant by setting up hyphenation. (I would say this is possibly the most common cause of bad linebreaking, so it was worth a guess). As for `\sloppy` that relaxes some things, if it is too much then obviously you can make a custom version that doesn't allow so much stretch but works for your line width and content. @MRule  better to post a new question than ask here

Answer (score 8):

if such a short word is at the end of a paragraph, i usually recommend "tie"ing it to the previous word with `~`.  if that results in an overfull line, i then apply `sloppypar` to the paragraph and let tex find the "best" way to reflow the paragraph.

Answer (score 1):

An example:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\setlength\textwidth{7.9cm}    
\begin{document}

\noindent\textbf{Normal Text}\par
How to break a line of text (\verb|\newline| or \verb|\\|) and still maintain justification for its texts? here is one bad.

\bigskip

\setlength\parfillskip{0pt plus .4\textwidth}
\setlength\emergencystretch{.1\textwidth}

\noindent\textbf{Stretched Text}\par
How to break a line of text (\verb|\newline| or \verb|\\|) and still maintain justification for its texts? here is one bad.

\end{document}
```

The most beautiful solution is to re-word your sentence(s). Another solution would be to restrict the `\parfillskip` and allow some `\emergencystretch` to compensate for this in the rest of the paragraph.

Comment: I respectfully submit that the central spirit of LaTeX is that the user should focus on making the best possible content and letting the language take care of the formatting - so re-wording a sentence into a less natural one solely to get around a technical limitation in the language is very much contrary to the spirit of LaTeX.